# Cannot find element in Galen Framework

Tags: galen

I am investigating Galen Framework to use it on new project.
**I am trying to submit form on Galen Demo aplication:**

http://samples.galenframework.com/tutorial-color-scheme/tutorial.html#

**I have this code in file submit-form.test.js**

this.SubmitPage = function (driver) {

GalenPages.extendPage(this, driver, {

nameTextfield: "xpath: //*[@id='content']/div/input", // xpath locator

submitButton: "xpath: //*[@id='content']/div/a", // xpath locator

});

};

test("Home page test", function () {

```
var driver = createDriver("http://samples.galenframework.com/tutorial-color-scheme/tutorial.html","1400x1100", "firefox");

var submitPage = new SubmitPage(driver);

submitPage.nameTextfield.typeText("Something");

submitPage.submitButton.click();  });
```

I run test with command
galen test submit-form.test.js --htmlreport reports

However, there is a next error in report:

**EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot call method "typeText" of undefined**

It seems thass Galen cannot find input field? Any help?

Comment: you missed the title:

Answer (score 0):

you missed the title:

```
this.SubmitPage = function (driver) {
  GalenPages.extendPage(this, driver, "Submit Page", {
    nameTextfield: "xpath: //*[@id='content']/div/input", // xpath locator
    submitButton: "xpath: //*[@id='content']/div/a" // xpath locator

  });
};


test("Home page test", function () {
  var driver = createDriver("http://samples.galenframework.com/tutorial-color-scheme/tutorial.html", "1400x1100", "firefox");

  var submitPage = new SubmitPage(driver);

  submitPage.nameTextfield.typeText("Something");
  submitPage.submitButton.click();

  driver.close();

});
```